# how to make continuous loop for SVG animation path's d

Tags: loops, animation, svg, path, indefinite

Can you advice how to make continuous loop for this back and forth animation of fire?

I use **begin="0s;animation2.end"**, **begin="animation1.end"** and **repeatCount="indefinite"** but it doesn't work

```
<path fill="#D4563D" d="M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418
    c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.307,24.36-21.51,38.384
    c-2.066,6.898-5.156,50.213-4.626,50.168C368.798,485.174,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z">
    <animate id="animation1"
             attributeName="d"
            attributeType="XML" 
             from="M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418
                c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.307,24.36-21.51,38.384
                c-2.066,6.898-5.156,50.213-4.626,50.168C368.798,485.174,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z"
             to="M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418
                c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.052,24.439-21.51,38.384
                c-8.141,25.465,10.927,50.364,11.422,50.168C391.047,471.82,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z" 
             dur="1s"
             />
    <animate id="animation2"
             attributeName="d"
             attributeType="XML"
             from="M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418
                c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.052,24.439-21.51,38.384
                c-8.141,25.465,10.927,50.364,11.422,50.168C391.047,471.82,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z" 
             to="M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418
                c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.307,24.36-21.51,38.384
                c-2.066,6.898-5.156,50.213-4.626,50.168C368.798,485.174,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z" 
             dur="1s" 
             begin="1s" />
</path>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify several key values of the animation in the `values` attribute of the `animate` element. They are semicolon-separated (as the [spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#ValuesAttribute)). The trick here is to declare an animation that goes from the first state to the intermediary state and back to the first state by using three key values, the first and the last being the same. With the `repeatCount` attribute set to `indefinite`, the animation continuously interpolates between the two states. Of course, the `dur` attribute must be doubled.

```
<path fill="#D4563D" d="M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418
    c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.307,24.36-21.51,38.384
    c-2.066,6.898-5.156,50.213-4.626,50.168C368.798,485.174,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z">
    <animate 
        attributeName="d"
        begin="0s"
        dur="2s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="
            M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418 c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.307,24.36-21.51,38.384 c-2.066,6.898-5.156,50.213-4.626,50.168C368.798,485.174,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z;
            M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418 c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.052,24.439-21.51,38.384 c-8.141,25.465,10.927,50.364,11.422,50.168C391.047,471.82,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z;
            M419.252,447.04c2.804-2.361,5.321-5.14,7.105-8.359c8.168-14.729-2.858-30.388-15.194-38.418 c-7.087-4.613-15.402-7.63-23.878-8.085c-8.877-0.478-20.522,1.64-27.462,7.462c-11.44,9.596-17.307,24.36-21.51,38.384 c-2.066,6.898-5.156,50.213-4.626,50.168C368.798,485.174,393.431,468.778,419.252,447.04z"
        />
</path>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `repeatCount="1"` and `begin="0s;animation2.end"` on first animation and `begin="animation1.end"` on second animation. Tested and working (on Chrome).